# One switch four lights

Tags: electrical-panel

I ran wire from the panel box to four shop lights then to the switch. The switch only turns off the last light closest to the switch. Have I completely messed myself up or is there still a way to have the switch turn off all for lights?

Comment: Yes, you blew it because you ran the wrong kind of **cable**.  You could've done it with /3 cable *between the lamps* but you used /2.  You cannot retrofit a single wire, the cable needs to be swapped.  Oh, also, Electrical Code now requires /3 between the last lamp and switch also.  That is to support future smart switches, motion sensor, lighted switch, whatevs.

Comment: @Harper -- post that as an answer and I'll +1 it :)

Comment: Depends on how you wired it. Daisy chain or parallel? Daisy chained would allow the switch to power on/off all lights. Parallel would only switch the last lamp in the series.

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you're designing a complex of lights and a switch, sketch it out using /3 cable (black white red, or the *wire functions* always-hot, neutral and switched-hot).

- Switches need all 3 wires.
- Lamps need switched-hot and neutral.
- Supply gives always-hot and neutral, obviously.

In your case, you will find you need /3 cable between all the lamps and the switch.

Sometimes you will find a segment where you just don't need all 3 of the wires - an example is a lamp past the switch.  In that case you can use /2 cable; possibly one of the wire colors will be wrong (an example is black when you want red) - just mark both ends of that wire with colored electrical  tape.

Don't get clever with switches and say "the switch only needs always-hot and switched-hot".  No, you also need to bring neutral to the switch; that has been Code for about a decade now.

If you want to do 3-way switches 2 or more switches in a multiway configuration, you need to run a separate /3 cable between the switches just for that purpose.